# JQ Query for nested values

Tags: json, jq

I'm sure this has been answered, but I can only find similar questions.. nothing which actually answers mine.

I have some JSON..

example:

```
{
    "Name": "test.example.net.",
    "Type": "A",
    "AliasTarget": {
        "HostedZoneId": "XXX12345XX54321",
        "DNSName": "test.example.net.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.",
        "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
    }
},
```

I want to return the Name, Type & DNSName only.

I've got close with..

```
.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.Type) \t\(.AliasTarget)"
```

But that returns the entire array `AliasTarget` - I'm trying to work out the correct syntax to pick out just `DNSName`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `jquery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `.AliasTarget.DNSName` to get the `.DNSName` **inside** the `.AliasTarget` object:

```
.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \t\(.Type) \t\(.AliasTarget.DNSName)"
```

```
"test.example.net. \tA \ttest.example.net.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com."
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vtMfBt7Lnv)